# Why does $\Bbb{F_2}[X]/(X^2)$ have characteristic $0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I am trying to understand dual numbers. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number#Algebraic_properties):

> In abstract algebra terms, the dual numbers can be described as the
>   quotient of the polynomial ring $R[X]$ by the ideal generated by the
>   polynomial $X^2$,
>
> $$R[X]/(X^2)$$
>
> The image of $X$ in the quotient is the unit $ε$. With this
>   description, it is clear that the dual numbers form a commutative ring
>   with characteristic $0$.

So I tried to make a simple example with $L=\Bbb{F_2}[X]/(X^2)$, which is $\{0,1,X,X+1\}$ (or is it $\{0,1\}$, since from $X^2=0 \in L$ it would follow that $X=0$?).

Now it says that the characteristic of this ring (I think it is even a field in both cases) is $0$, but $1+1=0$ in both cases. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: It is characteristic two allright. WP cannot always be trusted (and this feels like a typo anyway). The ring of dual numbers is not a field, so it is ok that there are non-zero elements with square equal to zero. You could find all this in a real textbook, I think.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen From the context, the $R$ actually is in bold and refers to the reals, so the claim on WP is correct.

Comment: So it seems, @TobiasKildetoft. The link wasn't there when I made my comment, so I could not check. Anyway, the ring $L$ in the question has characteristic two.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Under Generalization it says: "This construction can be carried out more generally: for a commutative ring $R$ one can define the dual numbers over R as the quotient of the polynomial ring $R[X]$ by the ideal $(X^2)$: the image of $X$ then has square equal to zero and corresponds to the element $ε$ from above."

Comment: Right, and the claim that it has characteristic zero is no longer there in that section. I do agree that it could have been explained more clearly though.

Comment: Alright, I thank both of you for clarification